# Alexa skill error when trying to return mp3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to let Alexa play an mp3 file that I'm storing in an AWS S3 bucket which is public. Everything works as it should when I try to trigger other intents but when I trigger the one with the audio file it triggers the error intent:

```
Sorry, I can't understand the command. Please say again.
```

Index.js file:

```
const PlayTheThreePiggletsIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'PlayThreePigletsIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const song = constants.audioData;

        return handlerInput.addAudioPlayerPlayDirective('REPLACE_ALL', song[1].url, '0', 10)
            .withShouldEndSession(true)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

constants.js:

```
exports.audioData = [
    {
        title: 'Gods plan',
        url: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kinderverhalen-template/tale2.mp3'
    },
    {
        title: 'The Three Piglets',
        url: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kinderverhalen-template/tale.mp3'
    }
];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't the error intent receive the actual error as its 2nd argument, and write it to the Lambda log with `console.log()`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you're right. The following error message was given: "handlerInput.addAudioPlayerPlayDirective is not a function".
Any idea why that is?

Comment: Apparently I forgot to add 'responseBuilder' after the handlerInput file... Working now

Comment: Please post the answer, with the code change, below... for the benefit of future visitors.